# symfony2 security roles

Tags: security, symfony

I want to do this in the security.yml file:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_EMPLEADO}
```

Which means that I want to have 2 roles accessing the same url pattern.

What I did doesn't work, it always give permission just to ROLE_ADMIN, and when I access the same url with ROLE_EMPLEADO it says Access Denied.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how you do it:

```
- { path: "^/admin", role: ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_EMPLEADO"] }
```

This will allow both roles to access the same url.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a role hierarchy (see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)

```
security:
  roles_hierarchy:
    ROLE_EMPLEADO: ROLE_ADMIN
```

which basically means a user with the role ROLE_EMPLEADO has also a role ROLE_ADMIN and then is enough to say:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :), but hierarchical roles doesn't fit my needs. I need empleado to be empleado. If I put ROLE_EMPLEADO: ROLE_ADMIN, then empleado would be admin too, and I wouldn't be able  to have something like: print this if you're empleado or print this if you're admin, because empleado would be both.